# Find PictureBox based on its image which is set using ResX resources

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox, embedded-resource

I have been trying to check if a `PictureBox` has a specific image. I've set the image of `PictureBox` using `Properties.Resources.TheImage`.

Using below code the image could not be found in any of `PictureBox` controls. I have been trying to make this to work:

```
foreach (Control X in Controls)
{
    if (X is PictureBox)
    {
        if (((PictureBox)X).Image == Properties.Resources.TheImage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("found the image");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

A `Properties.Resources.XxxxYyy` property will always return a new bitmap every time you use it. In general a nasty source of ballooning memory usage. You have to store it in a variable in your form constructor, now you can compare it.

Example :

```
Bitmap _icopalABitmap = Properties.Resources.IcopalA;
Bitmap _icopalBBitmap = Properties.Resources.IcopalB;
```

then u check the for specific image

Answer (score 0):

`Properties.Resources.SomeImage` returns different object reference each time which you use it. You cam simply test it:

```
var b = object.ReferenceEquals(Properties.Resources.SomeImage, 
                               Properties.Resources.SomeImage);
```

To check equality of images, you can use this method:

```
public bool AreImagesEqual(Image img1, Image img2)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    byte[] bytes1 = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img1, typeof(byte[]));
    byte[] bytes2 = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img2, typeof(byte[]));
    return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(bytes1, bytes2);
}
```

For example:

```
var b = AreImagesEqual(Properties.Resources.SomeImage, 
                       Properties.Resources.SomeImage);
```

Comment: It seems the post answers your question. Let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you find it useful :)